# how to change password in android using mysql (Registration and Login is perfectly working fine but issues in change password)

Tags: php, android, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```
class DbOperations{
    private $con;

    function __construct(){
        require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/db_connected.php';
        $db = new DbConnect();
        $this->con = $db->connect();
    }    

    public function changePassword($pass){
        $password = md5($pass);
        $stm = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE `student` SET `password` = ?
            WHERE `username` = ?);");
        $stm->bind_param("s",$password);
        $stm->execute();

        if ($stm) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now this is the function which i want to call for change password in android studio using php script.
All other file are not wrong the main problem is in this script name `DbOperations` function `changePassword`

This is change password script **userChangePassword.php**

```
<?php

    require_once '../include/db_operations.php';

    $response = array();
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        if (isset($_POST['password'])){
            $db = new DbOperations();
            if ($db->changePassword($_POST['password'])){
                $response['error'] = false;
                $response['message'] = "Change Password Successfully";
            }
            else{
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['message'] = "Password not changed";
            }
        }
        else{
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = "Fill all the feilds";
        }
    }
    else{
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Invalid Request";
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
```

**Error is :**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Android\include\db_operations.php on line 69

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stm = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE `student` SET `password` = ?
            WHERE `username` = ?);");
                                ^
```

This SQL statement is invalid -- the closing parenthesis I've marked (after `` `username` = ? ``) doesn't have a matching opening parenthesis anywhere. This causes the `prepare` call to fail.

```
 $stm->bind_param("s",$password);
 $stm->execute();
```

You haven't bound a value to the second parameter, corresponding to `username`. Nor is there a username argument to the function, or even to the `userChangePassword.php` script -- how is it supposed to know which user's password to update?

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to suggest that $stm is not set correctly.

```
   $stm = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE `student` SET `password` = ?
    WHERE `username` = ?);");
```

did not return a valid object. Are all the variables in your __construct function valid?

Edit: duskwuff is right, the closing parenthesis in `WHERE username = ?)` is incorrect

Comment: Yes all variables are valid because i am using it in registering user in database so this implies that all the variables are working fine